# The outcry against them has grown great

Tags: genesis, word-choice, lot

I'm currently reading through the Bible in one year plan and I have lots of questions!

It says in Genesis 19:13 (NKJV)

> 13 For we will destroy this place, because the outcry against them has grown great before the face of the Lord, and the Lord has sent us to destroy it.”

The verbiage, "the outcry against them has grown great", gives me a general sense that their sin has grown great. However, I'm wondering is there is an actual meaning. Like is this an idiom with a certain well know meaning? For example, "the grass is always greener on the other side" means that people tend to be dissatisfied with their own situation and always think that others have it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bible records various "*outcries against*" various indignities or grievous sins which arise from different sources.

- 1 Sam 4:13 - When he arrived, there was Eli, sitting on his chair beside the road and watching, because his heart trembled for the ark of God. When the man entered the city to give a report, the whole city **cried out**.
- Neh 5:1 - About that time there was a great **outcry** from the people and their wives against their fellow Jews.
- Jer 18:22 - Let an **outcry** be heard from their houses when You suddenly bring raiders against them, for they have dug a pit to capture me and have hidden snares for my feet.
- Jer 46:12 - The nations have heard of your shame, and your **outcry** fills the earth, because warrior stumbles over warrior and both of them have fallen together.”

So far, all these are humans giving an outcry to other humans.  However, the OP asks about those that come to the LORD which includes the following:

- Josh 24:7 - So your fathers cried out to the LORD, and He put darkness between you and the Egyptians, over whom He brought the sea and engulfed them. Your very eyes saw what I did to the Egyptians. Then you lived in the wilderness for a long time.
- Judges 3:15 - And again they cried out to the LORD, and He raised up Ehud son of Gera, a left-handed Benjamite, as their deliverer. So they sent him with tribute to Eglon king of Moab.
- Num 20:16 - and when we cried out to the LORD, He heard our voice, sent an angel, and brought us out of Egypt. Now look, we are in Kadesh, a city on the edge of your territory.
- 1 Sam 7:8 - and said to Samuel, “Do not stop crying out to the LORD our God for us, that He may save us from the hand of the Philistines.”
- 1 Sam 12:8 - When Jacob went to Egypt, your fathers cried out to the LORD, and He sent them Moses and Aaron, who brought your fathers out of Egypt and settled them in this place.
- 1 Sam 12:10 - Then they cried out to the LORD and said, ‘We have sinned, for we have forsaken the LORD and served the Baals and Ashtoreths. Now deliver us from the hands of our enemies, that we may serve You.’
- etc, etc

These are all instances of people crying out to God in prayer for help, or, about some injustice they witness.

Let us examine the texts quoted by the OP and two others:

- Gen 18:20, 21 - Then the LORD said, “The **outcry** against Sodom and Gomorrah is great. Because their sin is so grievous, 21I will go down to see if their actions fully justify the **outcry** that has reached Me. If not, I will find out.”
- Gen 19:13 - because we are about to destroy this place. For the **outcry** to the LORD against its people is so great that He has sent us to destroy it.”

The OP is essentially asking about this "outcry against the LORD". Who is doing it or is it merely a figure of speech?

I see no reason to read it anything but literally.  The question then becomes, Who is doing the outcrying?  Here are the various options:

- the abstract "outcry" is personified; that is, the LORD already knew but used a personified figure of speech to anthropomorphize the expression for the sake of communication with Abraham
- the outcry is literal in the form of prayers to God from both observers and the victims of extreme cruelty in the evil cities
- the outcry is from angel observers who are struggling to continue watching what they observe.

We are not explicitly told the answer to this question.  However, the only option that is consistent with other "outcries" is that from humans as per the many other examples of the same thing for which a few examples are quoted above.

Comment: That was informative. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We have two phrases here that emphasize the seriousness of Sodom's sin. First "the outcry against them has grown great." Second: "before the face of the Lord."

The "men" speaking here are understood to actually be angels and what they report to Abraham is that the behavior of the people of Sodom is so outrageous that it has offended God. We needn't necessarily think of an audible outcry, but rather a complaint delivered to God by spiritual messengers--or even, in modern slang, a major disturbance in the Force. The passage is reminiscent of what the Lord says more sympathetically in Exodus 3:9:

> Now indeed the outcry of the Israelites has come to me, and I have seen how the Egyptians are oppressing them.

Thus, idea of a public outcry heard by God can be either a complaint against wickedness or a plea for deliverance. See also 1 Samuel 5:12, Judges 10:10, 1 Chronicles 5:20.

Answer (score 0):

The previous chapter Abraham asks God if the city could be spared if but only a few are righteous in it. Abraham kept posing the question limiting the number. Only to find there are not any good people remaining in the city, save Lot and his family. The cry has to be in regard to the inhabitants' victims.
Given the mob wanted to rape the messengers God sent, it's quite evident the evil the people perpetrated.

Revelation 6:10 KJV

> and they cried with a loud voice, saying, How long, O Lord, holy and true, dost thou not judge and avenge our blood on them that dwell on the earth?

These are people who have died. This illustrates all victims are there before God.
And this is their cry.

Another example:

Genesis 4:9-10 KJV

> <sup>**9**</sup> And the Lord said unto Cain, Where is Abel thy brother? And he said, I know not: Am I my brother's keeper?<sup>**10**</sup> And he said, What hast thou done? the voice of thy brother's blood crieth unto me from the ground.

There comes a time when those victims cry so loud that God will be moved to enact His vengeance to comfort all who mourn.

Comment: +1. Well reasoned.